# Move deleted data from a table to another table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

What is the best way to move the deleted data from a table to another table? Assuming both tables have same column definitions?

```
EmpTable
EmpID(PK, identity) EmpName(nvarchar(max)) Picture(varbinary(max)) 

DeletedEmpTable
DeletedEmpID(PK, identity) EmpID(int) EmpName(nvarchar(max)) Picture(varbinary(max))
```

Comment: You can create delete trigger on first table, which will fire on deletes and copies/inserts deleted row into another table. Check [Sample Code here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-Audit-Table-and-5cd69d5d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table does not participate in foreign keys, have triggers, have an identity column, computed columns, etc. you may be able to do something like this with [the `OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
DELETE dbo.Table1
OUTPUT deleted.* 
INTO dbo.Table2
WHERE ...
```

You can work around some of these limitations by writing a more creative `OUTPUT` clause, but not all of them. If you have any restrictions that prevent the use of the `OUTPUT` clause, you could use an [`INSTEAD OF` trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to perform both operations.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerOnTable1
  ON dbo.Table1
  INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.Table2(cols) SELECT cols FROM deleted;

  DELETE t FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
    ON t.key_column = d.key_column;
END
GO
```

A lot of people question the value of `INSTEAD OF` triggers compared to regular after triggers. What I like about them is that if you have any validation to perform that might lead you to canceling the delete, you can cancel the delete instead of allowing it to happen and then rolling it back.

Comment: What if there is identity?

Comment: @Karlx where? Target? Destination? Both? Please be specific. Maybe include table definitions in your question?

Comment: @Karlx then use the trigger. PS why does the `DeletedEmpTable` have an identity column?

Comment: @Karlx Huh? Wouldn't EmpID serve as a PK? How many times can you delete an employee? Is this an "every table needs an identity column, whether it needs it or not" requirement?

Comment: I also used it for sorting instead of sorting it by datedeleted hehe. But I changed my mind, I will remove that identity and add the `DateDeleted`